# Azure function listBlobsFlat/listBlobsByHierarchy returning none

Tags: node.js, azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

i have this azure storage with the following structure:

```
 - Storage Accounts:
   -coobostorageprod
   --blob containers
   ---$logs
   ---roboprod
   ----nfe
   ----cte
```

i usually access to upload or download the folder nfe and cte with some code's like this to download and add up to a zip file:

```
const blobName = `nfe/NFe${row._id}.xml`
    const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName)
    const exists = await blobClient.exists()
    if (exists) {
      try {
        const downloadResponse = await blobClient.download()
        archive.append(downloadResponse.readableStreamBody, { name: `${row._id}.xml` })
      } catch (err) { console.log(`err1 ${err.message}`) }
    }
```

and like this to upload file:

```
// Upload to Azure
if (result && result.upsertedCount) {
  const blobName = `nfe/NFe${id}.xml`
  const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName)
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName)
  const exists = await blobClient.exists()
  if (!exists && xmlDoc) {
    await blockBlobClient.upload(xmlDoc, xmlDoc.length)
  }
}
```

i was trying to make a script to list all the files inside the nfe and download it to migrate for a new S3 server that is waiting for this data.

this code is returning empty:

```
  try {
    const response = containerClient.listBlobsFlat()
    if (!response || !response.segment || !response.segment.blobItems) {
      console.log('No blobs found in the container')
      return res.send('error')
    }

    for (const blob of response.segment.blobItems) {
      console.log(blob.name)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error listing blobs:', error.message)
  }
```

can someone help me with this ?

have already tried with the listBlobsByHierarchy too.

i will need to download all files inside the NFe/CTe and save all inside the AWS S3.

Comment: Please see the examples here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list-javascript. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `Gaurav Mantri`, for the comments.

I used the code from the [MSDoc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list-javascript)

I tried the below code and able to list blobs.

```
Blobs listing
```

[image]

Blobs in Azure portal.

[image]

```
let iter = containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy("/", { prefix: "prefix1/" });
let entity = await iter.next();
while (!entity.done) {
  let item = entity.value;
  if (item.kind === "prefix") {
    console.log(`\tBlobPrefix: ${item.name}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`\tBlobItem: name - ${item.name}`);
  }
  entity = await iter.next();
}
```

**Use a flat listing**

The below code lists the blobs in the specified container using a flat listing.

JavaScriptCopy

```
async function listBlobsFlatWithPageMarker(containerClient) {

  // page size - artificially low as example
  const maxPageSize = 2;

  let i = 1;
  let marker;

  // some options for filtering list
  const listOptions = {
    includeMetadata: false,
    includeSnapshots: false,
    includeTags: false,
    includeVersions: false,
    prefix: ''
  };

  let iterator = containerClient.listBlobsFlat(listOptions).byPage({ maxPageSize });
  let response = (await iterator.next()).value;

  // Prints blob names
  for (const blob of response.segment.blobItems) {
    console.log(`Flat listing: ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
  }

  // Gets next marker
  marker = response.continuationToken;

  // Passing next marker as continuationToken    
  iterator = containerClient.listBlobsFlat().byPage({ 
      continuationToken: marker, 
      maxPageSize: maxPageSize * 2 
  });
  response = (await iterator.next()).value;

  // Prints next blob names
  for (const blob of response.segment.blobItems) {
    console.log(`Flat listing: ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
  }
}
```